# Can't use intent to change activity inside a fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a logout button that sends me back to my login page activity but there's an error that I'm unsure of how to fix. The error occurs at the 'Profile_Fragment.this, LoginPage.class'.

Here is the source code

```
public class Profile_Fragment extends Fragment {
    Button btnLogout;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener
            
    StorageReference storageReference;
    private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private StorageTask uploadTask;
    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    //inflate the fragment
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnLogout = getView().findViewById(R.id.SignOutButton);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intToMain = new Intent(Profile_Fragment.this, LoginPage.class);
                startActivity(intToMain);
            }
        });
        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Intent intToMain = new Intent(Profile_Fragment.this, LoginPage.class);
```

`Profile_Fragment` is not a context. Replace it by `requireContext()` or `getActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

you can replace Profile_Fragment.this with a Context instance
In this case the activity hosting your Profie_Fragment will be the context.

you can replace Profile_Fragment.this with getActivity();

```
Intent intToMain = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginPage.class);
```

Note: getActivity() may return null, so you will have to check for the null value, also this is not the recommended way of handling navigation to activities. Your fragment should notify the hosting Activity about the navigation event and your Activity hosting that particular Fragment should be responsible for managing navigations. Checkout this link for better understanding https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#java